# Twilio Make a Call api, pass object instead of XML in URL parameter

Tags: c#, xml, twilio

While using Make a Call api, Twilio requires to input URL of an XML which should contain `<say>` element, which will convert the text into speech. I want to rather pass *say*, *action* and *method* (action and method attributes of *Gather* element) as an object. Is there a possibility in Twilio api? I want to receive some *Digits* entered by user during this call. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When making a call you always need to pass a URL that when called will return some XML (TwiML) to tell Twilio what to do with the call.

If you are looking to receive digits entered by a user, you will need to include the [`<Gather>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) in that XML. If you want a bit more detail than just the documentation, there is a tutorial available that takes you through [building a phone menu system using C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/csharp/mvc) that you might find helpful in this case. The tutorial starts with an incoming call, but the theory regarding `<Gather>` is the same.

Comment: I have successfully tested above mentioned XML (TwiML). Twilio's api are well documented and I didn't have any ambiguity in implementing it. I was bit more concerned about the whole XML thing that needs to be returned every time I use this api. It would be better if Twilio in future provides access and let its user directly post data (Say, Gather.. etc) in some kind of object rather than XML.

Comment: I think so far the API and interaction with it through TwiML has been designed for the best case between simplicity and flexibility. While I can see why you would want to provide Twilio with all the information for a simple call up front, if that got any more complicated your initial API call would become quite complicated, especially if you wanted to branch based on input digits to Gather. Then, at the point you needed to reach your database (or something in your app) you'd have to rewrite the whole app to use TwiML. So currently TwiML is the only way to interact with a call.

Comment: No worries, I've shared this post internally, so your ideas have been noted. :-)

Comment: I also think there should be a provision to pass text in the API call instead of making it available as url. It will require extra effort to make your text available at some public url while it should be seemless to provide text which will be called during the call